# Paginação ordenada por ID

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Tenho esse sistema como menu

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer com que ele passe os produtos e retorne por meio da ID salva no banco?

```html
<nav class="slider__nav">
<button class="button button--nav-prev"><i class="icon icon--arrow-left"></i><span class="text-hidden">Prev</span></button>
<button class="button button--zoom"><i class="icon icon--zoom"></i><span class="text-hidden">View</span></button>
<button class="button button--nav-next"><i class="icon icon--arrow-right"></i><span class="text-hidden">Next</span></button>
</nav>
```

Caso eu clique Next me apresenta o 2 e assim por diante.
E retroceda caso o Prev seja selecionado.

Comment: A minha dica seria, guarde o id atual numa variavel local e vai aumentando e use essa variavel para retornar o respectivo produto

Comment: teria algum tutorial ou algo parecido estou aprendendo mas só encotrei algo como paginação mas faz a contagem total e preciso de um por vez. para não prejudicar o view. tentei mas não me deu o segundo. O resultado somente sobrescreveu o segundo quando abri o view do primeiro.  se puder dar uma olhada na execução. http://imperionutry.esy.es/aula/index_prod_acao.php

Comment: Bem eu não tenho ideia de como fazer em php, nem tenho como demonstrar o código mas posso demonstrar a ideia. Se eu fosse fazer eu ia declarar uma váriavel no inicio do script php. E sempre que clicassem no botão `Next` eu ia adicionar `+1` à variável e chamar uma query sql tipo `SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE ID in ($idAtual)` e apresentasse as informações.

Comment: Se trata de uma paginação comum, porém com a  ressalva de que é apenas um registro por página, qual banco de dados você pretende utilizar? Essa troca de página utilizará uma chamada síncrona ou assíncrona, post ou get? Dê uma olhada nesse artigo para ver se esclarece um pouco mais a respeito de paginação http://blog.thiagobelem.net/entendendo-a-paginacao-de-registros-no-mysql